# Numpy: Create 2D array based on value from dict, using other 2D array value as index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have 2 2D numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']])
b = np.array([[0.01, 0.02, 0.03], [0.04, 0.05, 0.06]])
```

I aso have a dict with some values:

```
d = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, ... 'f':600}
```

Now I want to create a 2D array, based on the first 2, and my dict. Something like this:

```
c = b * d[a]
```

In other words, I want to manipulate array `b`, using a certain value (retrieved from the dict `d`) corresponding to a value in array `a` at the same index.

```
c = np.array([[1, 4, 9], [16, 25, 36]])
```

Is there any way to do this besides a nested loop?

Comment: You either access the dictionary elements by key in some sort of loop (hidden or explicit), or you use `keys/values/items` to pull out all the values and create some other structure that's more suitable for array use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vectorize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function on the `d.get` method to use the values of `a` as keys for `d`:

```
>>> np.vectorize(d.get)(a)
array([[100, 200, 300],
       [400, 500, 600]])
```

Note that this is implemented as a loop behind the scenes so it won't give you much (if any) performance benefit.

You can combine this into one line:

```
>>> b*np.vectorize(d.get)(a)
array([[  1.,   4.,   9.],
       [ 16.,  25.,  36.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vectorized approach making use of NumPy functions along the way -

```
# Convert strings in a to numeric labels
aID = (np.fromstring(a, dtype=np.uint8)-97).reshape(a.shape)

# Get the argsort for getting sorted keys from dictionary
dk = d.keys()
sidx = np.searchsorted(sorted(dk),dk)

# Extract values from d and sorted by the argsort indices.
# Then, index with the numeric labels from a and multiply with b.
d_vals= np.take(d.values(),sidx)
out = b*d_vals[aID]
```

Please note that the keys are assumed to be single character strings. If they are not in that format, you can use `np.unique` to get numeric labels corresponding to elements in `a`, like so -

```
aID = np.unique(a,return_inverse=True)[1].reshape(a.shape)
```

**Runtime test**

In this section, let's use those `6 keys` and bigger arrays and time all the approaches posted thus far including the original one suggested in the question -

```
In [238]: def original_app(a,b,d): # From question
     ...:     c = np.zeros(a.shape)
     ...:     for i in range(a.shape[0]):
     ...:         for j in range(a.shape[1]):
     ...:             c[i,j] = b[i,j] * d[a[i,j]]
     ...:     return c
     ...: 
     ...: def vectorized_app(a,b,d): # Proposed code earlier
     ...:     aID = (np.fromstring(a, dtype=np.uint8)-97).reshape(a.shape)
     ...:     dk = d.keys()
     ...:     sidx = np.searchsorted(sorted(dk),dk)
     ...:     d_vals= np.take(d.values(),sidx)
     ...:     return b*d_vals[aID]
     ...: 

In [239]: # Setup inputs
     ...: M, N = 400,500 # Dataisze
     ...: d = {'a': 600, 'b': 100, 'c': 700, 'd': 550, 'e': 200, 'f':80}
     ...: strings = np.array(d.keys())
     ...: a = strings[np.random.randint(0,6,(M,N))]
     ...: b = np.random.rand(*a.shape)
     ...: 

In [240]: %timeit original_app(a,b,d)
1 loops, best of 3: 219 ms per loop

In [241]: %timeit b*np.vectorize(d.get)(a) # @TheBlackCat's solution
10 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ms per loop

In [242]: %timeit vectorized_app(a,b,d)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.17 ms per loop

In [243]: np.allclose(original_app(a,b,d),vectorized_app(a,b,d))
Out[243]: True

In [244]: np.allclose(original_app(a,b,d),b*np.vectorize(d.get)(a))
Out[244]: True
```

Comment: Although this is vectorized, once you get through getting the unique values and sorting and searching, you lose the speed advantage of vectorizing.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Surely there is some overhead of setting up for vectorization. I guess would depend on the input data formats. With `d` I am hoping it has limited number of keys, so the sorting there won't be too costly. Let's see how it pans out with OP.

Comment: @TheBlackCat Well, got rid of `np.unique`! Must be much faster now, thanks a lot for the feedback!